# Calling an AJAX Enabled WCF Service from jQuery

Tags: wcf, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. My aim is to create a web service which will enable the client (mobile) to query against a database.

After some research, I found out that AJAX Enabled Services might be what I was looking for.
So, I began by creating an AJAX-Enabled WCF Service and for now I added only the following method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string GetString()
{
    return "Hello there";
}
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WebApplication1.MobileServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="WebApplication1.MobileService">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication1.MobileServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication1.MobileService" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

After finishing off this service, I called from the client using the following method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:11634/MobileService.svc/GetString",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
    $("#textbox").text(result);
    },        
    error: function (textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

When calling the service, I am getting the following error `[object Object]`. Can you guide me on what am I doing wrong and whether I am using the right technologies please?

Comment: [object Object] is not an error. You got the response as an JSON object. You need to parse the object to get the desired value. Most likely if you try result.d in your success callback, you will get the string. Use HTTP tracing tool like FireBug or HTTPFox to see exactly what you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

As Tariqulazam rightly points out [Object object] is not an error but a response object. To access the data you could modify your code to read:

```
success: function (result) {     
    var data = result.d
    $("#textbox").text(data);     
},
```

If you want to see a text-book example the following looks like a good example of jQuery code which consumes a WCF web-service:

[Consuming WCF service using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756103/consuming-wcf-service-using-jquery)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I checked firebug to check what error I am getting exactly, but i am getting a `NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: Hmmm, my best bet is that it's some kind of cross-domain problem - what address is your JavaScript code running at? I would recommend you use a relative URL instead of an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not passing parameters, I would change this to a GET call instead and remove the data portion of the ajax call. Also the way you were returning it was in XML format, change the response format to JSON

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetString", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string GetString()
    {
        return "Hello there";
    }

$.ajax({     
    type: "GET",     
    url: "http://localhost:11634/MobileService.svc/GetString",     
    contentType: "application/json",     
    dataType: "json",     
    success: function (result) {     
    $("#textbox").text(result);     
    },             
    error: function (textStatus) {     
        alert(textStatus);     
    }     
});
```

Comment: I did as you told me, but now I am getting the following error: NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change the ajax call type to "GET" also.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. I think you meant `[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] `. I changed the dataType to 'jsonp', but I am getting a new error `SyntaxError: invalid label`

Comment: No, keep it at WebGet, and dataType should be 'json' not jsonp, don't know if that was a typo or not :)

Comment: No it was not. I did it, because my service and my client application are on different domains. Please help!

Comment: I don't know why I didn't catch it earlier, but see my edits in my answer for the WCF service operation contract

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your 
    $.ajax({ ... })
inside a function call. That way on a specific action it is called.

Comment: Yes, it is wrapped in a click function.